# How to disable tabbaritems programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `tabbarcontroller` and it has 3 `tabbaritems`. in the first screen, there is a `button` and upon clicking that button i need to deactivate all the `tababritems` in the application.

How can I `deactivate` all the `tabbaritems` in the application programmatically?

[It looks something like this](http://fwd.dj/tmp/pic2.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to disable items so that they cannot be clickable or you want to just remove the image of tab bar items.

Comment: I want to disable items so it cannot be clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a BOOL property on your ViewController that has the button.

```
BOOL isInDisabledTabState;
@property BOOL isInDisabledTabState;
```

Then also implement the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol in your view controller.

```
MyViewController:UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

Set your view controller as the tab bar delegate on the tab bar.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self.tabBarController setDelegate:self];
}
```

Then when the button is pressed set the BOOL property to TRUE/FALSE accordingly.

```
-(IBAction) disableTabsButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.isInDisabledTabState = TRUE;
}
```

In your ViewController also implement the following protocol method in your view controller (See reference for UITabBarControllerDelegate)

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (self.isInDisabledTabState) {
        return FALSE;    // If in disabled state don't switch to the other tab
    }
    return TRUE;    // else switch.

}
```

Comment: Will this code disable all the `tabbaritems` of the `tabbarcontroller` ?

Comment: I haven't syntax checked it or runtime checked it but yes in theory thats what it should do (it assumes that the view controller with the 'disable tabs' button on it is the first view controller).  You might want to consider making the app delegate your tab bar controller delegate instead, setting the delegate just after the main view with the tab bar is loaded (or using an outlet in the nib to the owner), and having boolean switch in the app delegate as welll as this might be a slightly cleaner design.